# Unique Max in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table like this :

```
id         | date_r
1          | 2017-12-01
2          | 2017-12-06
1          | 2017-12-01
2          | 2017-12-03
3          | 2017-12-02
```

And I want to fetch all ids with max date.

I've done a query like this :

```
select t1.id, t2.date_r from table t1
inner join 
( select id, max(date_r) date_r_max from table group by id )t2
on t1.id=t2.id and t1.date_r=t2.date_r_max
```

And I have this result :

```
id         | date_r
1          | 2017-12-01
2          | 2017-12-06
1          | 2017-12-01
3          | 2017-12-02
```

But I want this result :

```
id         | date_r
1          | 2017-12-01
2          | 2017-12-06
3          | 2017-12-02
```

Anyone know how to get a unique max ?

My DB is Hive

Comment: you should use `group by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. When this piece of query could do the job, you complicated things by thinking of using `JOIN`

```
select id, MAX(date_r) date_r
               FROM t1 GROUP BY id;
```

You have also mentioned,

> And I want to fetch all ids with max date.

Does it mean something this ?

```
SELECT id,date_r FROM t1 WHERE 
         date_r IN ( select MAX(date_r) 
                         FROM t1 GROUP BY id );
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f174/4)